# PL/SQL Exception?

Tags: sql, oracle, exception

I have the following exception:

```
EXCEPTION
WHEN DateOverlapException THEN
      raise_application_error (-20001,'Dates are overlapping'); 
WHEN DateOrderException THEN
      raise_application_error (-20002,'Date order error has occured');
END;
```

If I remove the 2nd exception, it will run the script fine, but with it, It won't run the script. Just says compilation errors occured. Have no idea what the issue is. Anyone know? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming that you are using SQL*Plus, type "show errors" to get a list of the errors.  My guess is that the second exception isn't defined but there are other possible causes.  Without seeing the entire block or the error messages, it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the entire block to get quick answer.

Probably you are not declaring the DateOrderException  exception in your declare section.

```
declare
...
...
DateOrderException  exception;

begin
.....
....
EXCEPTION
WHEN DateOverlapException THEN
raise_application_error (-20001,'Dates are overlapping'); 
WHEN DateOrderException THEN
raise_application_error (-20002,'Date order error has occured');
END;
```